# Cannot reset iframe.style.height successfully using jS on IE8

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I have the following piece of JavaScript code:

```
var urlpxExt = document.getElementById('urlPx');
urlpxExt.style.height = "200px";
```

This is very a general way to reset iframe style height, My problem is that the height of iframe 'urlPx' does not reset successfully on IE8,  The size of iframe does not changed on my view of IE screen, then I tried to alert `urlpxExt.style.height` after line `urlpxExt.style.height = "200px"`, it ouput the value which was not be changed.

If I add some time-consuming process like alert before `urlpxExt.style.height = "200px"`. then it will reset value successfully.

Anybody know why I got this happened? How to resolve?

Comment: Could you try to recreate your problem on either [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: Sounds like your `urlPx` element has not loaded yet. Try wrapping your JavaScript in `$(document).ready` if you're using jQuery, or `window.onload` if you're not.

Comment: It has ready loaded completely. I will try to reproduce http://jsbin.com/omodi5/edit but I am not sure it will be reproducible on there.

Comment: Did you try moving your script to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Try to output `urlpxExt` to console using `console.log(urlpxExt)` immediately after defining it. Also, you should probably use the `onload` event of your iframe instead of using `onload` event of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps IE8 is treating your iframe as a text-level inline element (for which a `height` style cannot be specified. Try setting the CSS `display` property for your iframe to `block`, and see if your problem persists.

Also, remember that the iframe element supports an HTML `height` attribute, which means you should be able to set it using `iframeElement.height = [number]`.